# How to repair encrypted disk after unfinished formatting?

Tags: macos, disk-management, recovery-disk, journaled

I've accidentally started formatting of encrypted macos journaled external hdd. 5 seconds after start, I've unplagged hdd to stop the process. Now it isn't mounting. Is there a way to restore data integrity somehow?

HDD was encrypted by macos tools (right click in finder -> encrypt).

Disk utility first aid is printing following:

```
Repairing storage system
Performing fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/disk3s2
Checking volume.
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
error: (oid 0x403) apfs: _omap_lookup_obj(0x403, 0x15ca2b3): No such file or directory
error: failed to read object (oid (0403)) being reaped from disk 
The volume /dev/disk3s2 could not be verified completely.
Storage system check exit code is 0.
Operation successful.
```

Comment: You’re using `fsck_apfs` when it’s not APFS. // That being said, your priority should be to unlock the encryption. Only after that can you attempt to recover what’s left. Which probably won’t be a lot, seeing how the start of the partition contains critical information.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230379/recover-deleted-encrypted-os-x-extended-volume

Comment: You might have better luck on the apple.stackexchange.com site. Guessing you'll need to start understanding file systems & the first couple sectors of the drive. I FEEL like this can be fixed, but I am sure its going to take hours & command-line kungfu for someone of moderate skill set. If the data is super important I'd be looking at when your last backup was & all else fails contacting a data recovery expert which is likely to be expensive

Comment: In general try to understand if you have overwritten the key used to encrypt the disk, and hope not. If you have that key you can start hoping to have some chance to recover the rest... Good luck.

Comment: @HackSlash this comment reads like: "I don't want to add any valuable info, I just want to be toxic with obvious statements"

Comment: If it's obvious that you destroyed the data then you wouldn't be asking the question. Telling you that encryption destroys data is not toxic and is valuable as it explains why you don't have an answer despite placing a large bounty.

Comment: @HackSlash I know what is encryption and how it works. If you check out Tetsujin's link, you find out (besides example of useful comment), that there are possibility of preserving data if problem is related only to partition table.